# How to prevent uninstallation of application automatically?

Tags: android, uninstallation

Some users of my application say that application is uninstalled suddenly from their phone.
It was reported by more than one user. What can be the cause and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: The only time I've known this to happen is if your app gets flagged as malware or a trojan - Google will then automatically remove it from users phones. What is the app called? Check your Play Store developer account to see if there are any notifications. If this is what's happening, then the only way to stop it is to remove the malware.

Comment: Of course ;) Seriously - is there a policy of uninstall of app by Google? Again - it does not ALWAYS happen, just for some users and in certain times. I cannot reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can be the cause?

Perhaps your users are confused. For example, perhaps you are playing some `PackageManager` tricks and wind up disabling your launcher activity. Users might mistake that for your app having been uninstalled, even though it is installed.

Or, perhaps your users are drunk.

> How can I prevent this from happening?

Don't disable your launcher activity.

Or, ask your users to not use your app while drinking.

> is there a policy of uninstall of app by Google?

Only in the case of identifiable malware, in which case it would be all copies of your app, not some subset.